# MySql Adding date range by month

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that was working fine until I added in a date range:

`WHERE c.content_date BETWEEN MONTH($date) AND MONTH($today)`

Basically I want to get all content from the inputed date until today by month. So for example if `$today` was `2017-1-23` and `$aDate` was `2016-11-20` I would want all content from November until January (of next year)

Query

```
 $result = DB::query("SELECT ".Content::$mDefaultContentListSelect."  
                    FROM crowdhub_content_to_buckets ctb 
                    LEFT JOIN crowdhub_content c 
                    WHERE c.content_date BETWEEN MONTH($date) AND MONTH($today)
                    ON ctb.crowdhub_content_to_buckets_content = c.content_id 
                    WHERE ctb.crowdhub_content_to_buckets_bucket IN ( SELECT bucket_id FROM crowdhub_buckets b WHERE b.bucket_name IN %ls ) 
                    AND ctb.crowdhub_content_to_buckets_content 
                    IN (SELECT content_to_tag_content AS content_id FROM crowdhub_content_to_tags 
                    WHERE content_to_tag_tag IN (SELECT tag_id FROM crowdhub_tags WHERE tag_name IN %ls)) ".$active." ORDER BY ".$sort_string." LIMIT ".($aCount * $aPageId).",".$aCount, $buckets, $tags);
```

Comment: Please post the error that you are getting

Comment: Can exist any date > $today?

Comment: not getting an error, just no content. If I remove that I get all content

Comment: 1st or 31st January?

Answer (score 0):

This should return the first day of the month:

```
DATE_SUB($date, INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH($date)-1 DAY)
```

and this the last day of the month:

```
LAST_DAY($today)


WHERE c.content_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB($date, INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH($date)-1 DAY) AND LAST_DAY($today)
```

Answer (score 0):

If datatype of the `content_date` column is **`DATE`** (and we're just guessing, we have no way of knowing that)...

When comparing a `DATE` expression to an *integer* value, the date expression is going to evaluated as an *integer*. A date value of '2016-12-21' will evaluate to an *integer* value north of 20 million.  20,161,221 to be exact.

And that integer value is not going to be less than or equal to 12.

---

As a demonstration:

```
 SELECT MONTH('2016-12-21')
```

will return integer value of `12`.

---

So, remove that `MONTH` function. And think about what `date` values you want to compare to. And use expressions that evaluate to those date values.

---

*"if $today was 2017-01-23 and $aDate was 2016-11-20 I would want all 
content from November until January (of next year)"*

Then do the comparison to the *date* values. It seems like you want something that will be equivalent to:

```
WHERE c.content_date >= '2016-11-01'
  AND c.content_date <  '2017-02-01'
```

Those conditions will be TRUE (only) for all `content_date` values in November 2016, December 2016 and January 2017.

We can use expressions that evaluate to those date values.  Using the date values as given in the question, something like this:

```
WHERE c.content_date >= DATE_FORMAT( '2016-11-23' ,'%Y-%m-01') 
  AND c.content_date <  DATE_FORMAT( '2017-01-23' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH,'%Y-%m-01')
```

---

If you are going to be doing variable substitution into the SQL text, note that *date* literals should be enclosed in *single quotes*. Without single quotes, the dashes are going to be seen as subtraction operators

compare:

```
  SELECT '2016-12-21'
```

to:

```
  SELECT 2016-12-21      -- evaluates to integer value 1983
```